# why can i see my files under project in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, project

I can't see all my files in the project tab but when i switch to the project files then only can I see them. In another project I can see all files in both the project and project files tab so what's wrong with this project?

[image: under project]

[image: under project files]

Tried deleting the .idea file and restarting pycharm, didnt work.

Comment: @sbottingota this question is about a tool directly used to program, IDE questions are on-topic on SO.

Comment: Try going to the cog on the right side of the project tab, following this trail: `Project tab` `>` `Project Files` `>` `click the cog` `>` `Tree appearance` `>` `Show Excluded Files` as show in the documentation for [Show Excluded Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2022.1/project-tool-window.html#show_excluded_files).

Answer (score 0):

Update: I managed to fix it by adding content root in project structure.